# textbox round corner asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, textbox, rounding

im using   [javascript](http://code.google.com/p/rocon/downloads/list) for round corner 
its only works when i click the textbox.  If the textbox lost focus then the textbox again become rectangle where im wrong, heres the code

```
<script src="Jquery/rounded-corners.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <asp:TextBox CssClass="rounded rc5 FilterCriteria" ID="txtSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 <ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="ftxtSearch" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtSearch" FilterType="Numbers" />
<style>
    .rounded { 
    background:white;
    white-space:nowrap;
    zoom:1;
    } 
    .rc5 {
        border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: i solved this problem by removing ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But you are not using javascript to round the textbox corners. All what you do is using border-radius means that you are using style(CSS 3.0) to round textbox corners; your browser must be compatible with CSS3.0

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines in your stylesheet

```
 -moz-border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
 -webkit-border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
 border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
```

Comment: but still its not working when i click the textbox it bocomes rounded and if i unselect the textbox then it becomes rectangle again in all browsers

Comment: What are trying to achieve with added javascript?